# Why is my MongoDB returning "Topology was destroyed"?

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, api, topology

I've created a FrontEnd App with React. I have a lot of API Calls, maybe one APICall per route (Component). You enter a Component and you have an API Call from inside a UserEffect() hook. But sometimes, erratically, this error happens and everything just dies:

```
{
    "error": "Topology was destroyed"
}
```

I asked my Backend guy to do some checking on our Mongo Database and this is what he gave me:

```
020-07-31T14:59:17.901Z I -        [conn669] end connection 172.17.0.1:37860 (136 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.930Z I -        [conn637] end connection 172.17.0.1:53182 (99 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.930Z I -        [conn636] end connection 172.17.0.1:39666 (98 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.931Z I -        [conn635] end connection 172.17.0.1:34118 (97 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.931Z I -        [conn634] end connection 172.17.0.1:58554 (96 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.931Z I -        [conn633] end connection 172.17.0.1:55642 (95 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.931Z I -        [conn632] end connection 172.17.0.1:53584 (94 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.931Z I -        [conn631] end connection 172.17.0.1:48484 (93 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.931Z I -        [conn630] end connection 172.17.0.1:42048 (92 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.931Z I -        [conn629] end connection 172.17.0.1:42040 (91 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.931Z I -        [conn628] end connection 172.17.0.1:55528 (90 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.931Z I -        [conn627] end connection 172.17.0.1:55524 (89 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.931Z I -        [conn626] end connection 172.17.0.1:51082 (88 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.932Z I -        [conn625] end connection 172.17.0.1:43074 (87 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.932Z I -        [conn623] end connection 172.17.0.1:33006 (86 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.932Z I -        [conn622] end connection 172.17.0.1:42116 (85 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.932Z I -        [conn621] end connection 172.17.0.1:54526 (84 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.932Z I -        [conn620] end connection 172.17.0.1:54522 (83 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.932Z I -        [conn619] end connection 172.17.0.1:49528 (82 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.932Z I -        [conn617] end connection 172.17.0.1:32772 (81 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.932Z I -        [conn616] end connection 172.17.0.1:57102 (80 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.932Z I -        [conn615] end connection 172.17.0.1:58836 (79 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.932Z I -        [conn614] end connection 172.17.0.1:58832 (78 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.933Z I -        [conn613] end connection 172.17.0.1:34712 (77 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.933Z I -        [conn612] end connection 172.17.0.1:34708 (76 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.933Z I -        [conn611] end connection 172.17.0.1:59856 (75 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.933Z I -        [conn610] end connection 172.17.0.1:44736 (74 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.933Z I -        [conn609] end connection 172.17.0.1:56176 (73 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.933Z I -        [conn608] end connection 172.17.0.1:56172 (72 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.933Z I -        [conn607] end connection 172.17.0.1:54086 (71 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.933Z I -        [conn606] end connection 172.17.0.1:54082 (70 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.933Z I -        [conn605] end connection 172.17.0.1:39930 (69 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.933Z I -        [conn604] end connection 172.17.0.1:37762 (68 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.946Z I -        [conn603] end connection 172.17.0.1:38752 (67 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.947Z I -        [conn602] end connection 172.17.0.1:38178 (66 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.947Z I -        [conn601] end connection 172.17.0.1:55712 (65 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.947Z I -        [conn600] end connection 172.17.0.1:55688 (64 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.947Z I -        [conn599] end connection 172.17.0.1:48207 (63 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.947Z I -        [conn597] end connection 172.17.0.1:48178 (62 connections now open)

2020-07-31T14:59:17.947Z I -        [conn596] end connection 172.17.0.1:48174 (61 connections now open)
```

Do you have any idea on what's wrong with the API calls? Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have the lifetime of your objects wrong. Since node is running code asynchronously this is a common problem. You are getting the client closed earlier than you think it is closed.

Comment: Alright. Can I solve this from the FrontEnd? How do I set up the lifetime of my objects?

Comment: I think I know what is happening. But I don't know how to fix it. Everytime I go to a new component it calls a new API route. When I change the component, that route keeps open. Give it some time and I'll have thousands of routes. How do I kill all other routes (except login, of course), when moving to a new component?

Comment: Unless you are talking to mongodb from your frontend this isn't where the issue is.